# nvidia-smi show cuda version N/A

Tags: nvidia, cuda, docker

I try to use nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04 image to create a new caffe image.

But when I export container to tar file and import image to run new container,I use nvidia-smi cuda version to show version N/A.

I try:

1. docker export container_id > image.tar
2. cat image.tar | docker import - new_image:latest
3. docker run -i -t --gpus all new_image /bin/bash

Did I lose some steps? 
Before I expored nvidia-smi cuda version to show 10.1.